# Node JS passing an JavaScript object that could be undefined to pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My route needs to pass a series of JavaScript objects to the pug template.

```
router.get('/edit/:itemObjectId', async function(req, res, next) {
    var itemObjectId = req.params.itemObjectId;
    var equipmentCategoryArr = [];
    var lifeExpectancyArr = [];
    var businessUnitResponsibleArr = [];
    var item = undefined;

    try {
        item = await db_item.getItem(itemObjectId);

        // Where item["result"] is either undefined or a JavaScript Object. E.g. {"createdAt":"2018-11-07T04:07:44.587Z","updatedAt":"2018-11-07T04:25:18.526Z","item_name":"GM Portable","manufacturer":"GM"}
        res.render('editItem', {
            title: 'Edit item details', // Give a title to our page
            item: item["result"],
            equipmentCategoryArr: req.app.locals.equipmentCategoryArr,
            lifeExpectancyArr: req.app.locals.lifeExpectancyArr,
            businessUnitResponsibleArr: req.app.locals.businessUnitResponsibleArr
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ "Error": err }));
    }
});
```

Where

`item["result"]` could be either undefined or a JavaScript object.

On the editItem.pug page, I need to use the item in JavaScript.

```
block extraScript
    script.
        console.log(!{JSON.stringify(item)});
```

However, it renders like "`console.log();`" if item that was passed is undefined. So `!{JSON.stringify(item)}` was not rendered at all.

How can I check if item is undefined or not on the fron-end?

Comment: Why are you negating the results of JSON.parse?  You aren't seeing a false value being logged out?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate this in three places, all using the ternary operator ( `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse` )

In the route you can switch it from being undefined to an empty object

```
item: item["result"] ? item["result"] : {}
```

In the template you could apply the same logic:

```
console.log(!{ item ? JSON.stringify(item) : '{}' } );
```

You are going to need to do one of the two things above to make sure that something is getting rendered into the client-side code, otherwise you're going to face a syntax error from an empty expression:

```
var item = ;
```